# Changing class name of next select element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I can change property of second select element if i have code like this..

```
<select class="services_list1">
<option>Value 1</option>
  <option>Value 2</option>
</select>
<select class="services_list2">
<option>Value 1</option>
  <option>Value 2</option>
</select>
```

But the problem is, I am having two select element as following.. How to change the class name of second services_list2 on onchange() of services_list1.

```
 <td>
        <select class="services_list1">
<option>Value 1</option>
  <option>Value 2</option>
</select>
    </td>
    <td>
        <select class="services_list2">
<option>Value 1</option>
  <option>Value 2</option>
</select>
    </td>
```

Comment: can you share the js code as well??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get the select element in the next `td` element of current `td`

```js
$('.services_list1').change(function(){
  $(this).parent().next().find('select').toggleClass('something')
})
```

```css
.something{
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <select class="services_list1">
        <option>Value 1</option>
        <option>Value 2</option>
        <option>Value 3</option>
      </select>
    </td>
    <td>
      <select class="services_list2">
        <option>Value 1</option>
        <option>Value 2</option>
      </select>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```